Symfony HTTP client stops proxy requests halfway when reverse-proxying Apache Superset in embedded mode in my application
I'm facing a problem where my Symfony controller, acting as a reverse proxy to Apache Superset, stops processing requests halfway. When I make direct requests to Superset, everything works fine, but through the Symfony proxy, the requests don't complete.
I'm using Apache Superset Version: 3.1.2
What I've tried:
Direct requests: Direct requests to Superset from the browser work perfectly.
Reverse Proxy via Symfony: Requests via Symfony's reverse proxy stop halfway.
Logs and debugging :
Symfony logs checked (var/log/dev.log or var/log/prod.log).
No clear error message indicating why requests stop.
What I need:
Possible causes: Ideas on what could be causing proxy requests to stop halfway.
Debugging tips: How to effectively debug this problem in Symfony.
Configuration adjustments: Any configuration in Symfony or Superset that could prevent this problem.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your help.
The first image below shows the direct requests to apache superset
[he other two images trace reverse proxy requests via symfony (http client curl) up to the point where they stop, and also the error in the console.]
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBP2OiJf.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/rED8t2lk.png)
Here's my front :
supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
                        id: data.embeddedCode, // given by the Superset embedding UI
                        supersetDomain:  "{{path('superset_reverse_proxy')}}",
                        mountPoint: containerDashboard, // any html element that can contain an iframe
                        fetchGuestToken: () => data.guest_token,
                        dashboardUiConfig: {}, // dashboard UI config: hideTitle, hideTab, hideChartControls (optional)
                    })

Here's my Controller:
    /**
     * @Route("/superset/proxy/{any}", defaults={"any" = null}, name="superset_reverse_proxy", requirements={"any"=".+"})
     */
    public function supersetProxy(Request $request, $any): Response
    {
        $supersetUrl = 'supersetDomain'; // URL de votre instance Superset
        $targetUrl = $supersetUrl . $request->getRequestUri();
        $guestToken = $request->getSession()->get('guest');
        $csrfToken = $request->getSession()->get('csrf');

        $targetUrl = str_replace('/superset/proxy', '', $targetUrl);

        $headers2[] = 'Accept:application/json';
        $headers2[] = 'Content-Type:application/json';
        $headers2[] = 'X-CSRFToken: ' . $csrfToken;
        $headers2[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $guestToken;
        $headers2[] = 'Accept:application/json';

        $headers2[] = 'X-CSRF-Token: ' . $csrfToken;

        $headers2[] = 'X-GuestToken: ' . $guestToken;

        $headers2[] = 'X-Guest-Token: ' . $guestToken;

        $error = null;
        $info = null;
        $requestMethod = $request->getMethod();
        $responseContent =  $this->curlRequest2($targetUrl, $headers2, $requestMethod, [], $error, $info, $request);

        $responseContent = str_replace(array('href="/static/appbuilder/', 'href="/static/assets/', 'src="/static/appbuilder/', 'src="/static/assets/'), array('href="/superset/proxy/static/appbuilder/', 'href="/superset/proxy/static/assets/', 'src="/superset/proxy/static/appbuilder/', 'src="/superset/proxy/static/assets/'),$responseContent);
        $finalResponse = new Response($responseContent);

        $finalResponse->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'self' $supersetUrl");

        return $finalResponse;
    }

    public function curlRequest2($url, $header, $requestMethod = 'GET', $payload = [], &$error = null, &$info = null, $request = null)
    {
        $cURLConnection = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        if($request != null){
            $content = $request->getContent();
            if (!empty($content)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
            }
        }

        $response = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
        curl_close($cURLConnection);

        return $response;
    }

